# How to identify the script being run by a powershell task

Tags: powershell, windows-11

I'm running a `powershell` script on `Windows 11`. The process was started automatically by the task scheduler and is working as expected.

I can see a couple of `powershell` tasks running as 'background processes' in the task-scheduler. How can identify the name of the script being run? Basically I want to kill the process, but would like to confirm beforehand that I've identified the correct one.

I've tried right-clicking on the task, but `properties` only seem to show the powershell properties NOT the script details.

Comment: Try `Process Explorer` tool instead of built-in `Task Manager` - it might be able to reveal more info. https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Answer (score 1):

If you know the script is executed by `Task Scheduler`, then the easiest way to manually stop it is using `Task Scheduler` - just find the task and click "End" in the context menu:

[image]